# Twitter bootstrap modal goes behind iframe

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know how, but it happens: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9g2y/)

When showing twitter bootstrap 3 modal, it goes behind video iframe.

```
<div class="modal fade">
    ...
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/your_favorite_video" allowfullscreen="" ></iframe>
```

it seems z-index cannot help too.

---

UPDATE:

I use *Mozilla Firefox 25.0.1 for ubuntu canonical 1.0*.

Other browers are fine:

- Mozilla Firefox on windowse is fine
- Opera on Ubuntu is fine
- ...

Comment: What browser are you testing in? Works fine in Chrome (latest prod) for OSX.

Comment: Works on latest Chrome and Firefox on Windows

Comment: @r3mus , Mozilla Firefox 25.0.1 for ubuntu canonical 1.0

Comment: Inclined to think that's a bug in the Firefox rendering instead -- works in Chrome-latest, Firefox 22.0 for OSX, and I even tried in IE10

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make iframe respect z-index in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278390/how-can-i-make-iframe-respect-z-index-in-ie)

Comment: It's not related to Ubuntu. I've got the same issue in IE11 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from here: [YouTube Video Embedded via iframe Ignoring z-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074365/youtube-video-embedded-via-iframe-ignoring-z-index)

This did the trick for me on your fiddle

```
//Fix z-index youtube video embedding
$(document).ready(function (){
$('iframe').each(function(){
var url = $(this).attr("src");
$(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent");
});
});
```

Comment: since dynamic videos are shown, using `$(document).ready` is hard. can one do it by css?

Answer (score 0):

You can Just add the query param, "wmode=transparent," to the src URL for the embedded video:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/your_favorite_video?wmode=transparent" allowfullscreen="" ></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however, i do not remember the problem anymore.